# Site really slow for registered users

Tags: views, 6

When I look at the devel query logs of my website I see that views takes up most of the loading time. Anonymous loads of my page are much faster compared to registered loads but how come? Isn't views loaded the same way for every user?

Comment: Hard to say if you don't know the site at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Views supports caching the query and the rendering.

If you have page caching enabled then it's obviously much faster and views isn't involved at all.

There is no silver bullet to improve performance, try to install xhprof to find out where your bottlenecks are.

Using a different cache backend like memcached can help a lot, for a start.